# drupal client invoke an api asp.net

Tags: 7

i want to create a drupal 7 site that invoke an `APi asp.net` , when user login by email or user name if he already exist and password ('[module login tobaggon](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)') it invoke the  api asp.net to check if that user exist on the database sql server and return result to the drupal site if the user is already exist in sql server drupal show the offers of the site or if the user does't exit we invite him to sing in with his email 
how to create an client php that invoke and consume this api asp.net ('module')?
how to create that api asp.net ? 
thank u